# How to use different threads to safely update C structure using openmp

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, openmp

I am writing a randomAnimalGenerator.  It is a multithreaded C program, using VS2010, for Windows X64, and will be used to randomly generate animals for a zoo.

How can I make it so that the different threads all safely write to the members of a global structure ("zoo"), without implementing locks on the zoo structure?  The
values of the global structure will always only be incremented (++), and not decremented (--).   In the code below, without using OMP, the lions, tigers and bear each correctly have the value of 45,000.   But using the parallel loop the values do not equal 45,000.

Is there a way to make Openmp schedule these writes to the same variable without messing with making a private version of the structure?

```
#define LIONS 1
#define TIGERS 2
#define BEARS 3

// global struct
struct 
{
    int lions;
    int tigers;
    int bears;
} zoo;


void addAnimalsToZoo(void)
{
    int animalType = randomAnimalGenerator();

    if (animalType == LION)
        ++zoo.lions;
    else
    if (animalType == TIGER)
        ++zoo.tigers;
    else
    if (animalType == BEAR)
        ++zoo.bears;
    else
        printf("unknown animal type generated\n");
}


void myZooMaker(void)
{

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 45000; ++i)
        addAnimalsToZoo();
}
```

Comment: So then I can assume that OpenMp will correctly schedule things, so that if 2 or more threads both try to ++zoo.lions at precisely the same moment, there will be no problem with data racing, etc?  I can't find anything in the documentation about this.

Comment: It will be inefficient to have each thread write to the same shared data structure.  Instead you should have each thread write to a private version of the data structure.  Then merge each private version in a critical section.  This will be efficient and safe.

Comment: Actually, I was just able to write a different case and discovered that this is not thread safe.  I have edited my qeustion.

Comment: That should be a complete c*********k since `++` is not guaranteed to be atomic and you will have multiple threads all having a go at `zoo` simultaneously.  This is pretty much the definition of a data race.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, yes you are correct, although I'm not sure what c*******k is.  I have edited my question, but it looks like I cannot easily implement this in a parallel loop....or at least it is beyond my sorry programming skills...

Comment: Whatever it is c*******k is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some major refactoring your program won't work properly. As already noted the program exhibits a canonical data race, multiple threads simultaneously updating a shared data structure with no coordination.

You could:

1. Strip the variables `lions`, `tigers` and `bears` out of the struct (I'll explain why in a moment).
2. Modify `randomAnimalGenerator` to return, with the appropriate probability, one of the animals.

Then, and this is approximate because I'm not much of a C programmer, rewrite along these lines

```
int lions;
int tigers;
int bears;

lions = 0;
tigers = 0;
bears = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(i) reduction(+:lions, +:tigers, +:bears)
for (int i = 0; i < 45000; ++i)
{
    int newAnimal;
    newAnimal = randomAnimalGenerator();
    if (newAnimal==LION) ++lions;
    if (newAnimal==TIGER) ++tigers;
    if (newAnimal==BEAR) ++bears;
}
```

and at the end of this the variables `lions`, `tigers` and `bears` should sum to `45000`.  Notice the use of the reduction clause and the declaration of default accessibility as `shared`.  OpenMP reductions can't be applied to elements of structs or to structs as a whole which is why I threw `zoo` away.

I don't guarantee that the code is right but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I now know how to pursue this.  Now on to that randomAnimalGenerator(), right after I finish the cold fusion generator.